# Proving conditional probability property.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If if $A$ and $B$ are mutually disjoint (exclusive), then:

$$\mathbb{P}(A|A\cup B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)}$$

So I suppose that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ has to occur after the event $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$ occured..But I just dont know how to show that mathematically.

Comment: $A$ doesn't have to occur after $A\cup B$.  What $\Bbb P(A\mid A\cup B)$ is, is "the probability that event A occurred given that either event A or event B occurred".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of conditional probability:

$$\mathsf P(A\mid C) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap C)}{\mathsf P(C)}$$

Substitute: $C = A\cup B$

Simplify the numerator, and use the Law of Total Probability (for disjoint events) on the denominator.

That is all.

Comment: Ok thank you!!! But how can I get rid of the $B$ in the numerator?

Comment: $A\cap(A\cup B)$ can be simplified using the rules of set algebra. @Mamba

Answer (score 2):

There is no before and after. The notation 
$$
P(A|B) 
$$
does not mean that A comes after B in temporal sense.

What is the probability of rain in the next hour given that the sky is dark?

What is the probability that it was raining one hour ago given that the sky is dark?

Comment: @ Your point has been already made by Graham. So why put that as a solution? But still thx.